# Wrong image appearing as button background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having some difficulty working with buttons and images. I have 2 buttons, one next to the other, but the second one appears the wrong image. It shows a image with some tools.

Here is my code:

```
TextView categoriaText = new TextView(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);  
// use same id as defined when adding the button  
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 1001);
params.topMargin = top;
params.leftMargin = 30;
categoriaText.setLayoutParams(params);  
categoriaText.setText(_listaCategorias.get(i).getNome());
categoriaText.setTextSize(20);


Button deleteBtn = new Button(this);  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60,  
            60);  
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params2.rightMargin = 80;
params2.topMargin = top;
deleteBtn.setLayoutParams(params2);

deleteBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_coleccao);
// give the button an id that we know  
deleteBtn.setId(1001);  


Button editBtn = new Button(this);  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60,  
           60);  
// params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1001);
params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);  
params3.topMargin = top;
editBtn.setLayoutParams(params3);  
editBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_edit);
```

Here is a screenshoot: 
[image: Screen Shot]

The second image is not the correct one.

Comment: Your question is kind of not related to the code you posted. After all your problem is in the image name and not the code itself.

Comment: try (Eclipse Menu) *Project > Clean*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens more often that references to resources in the R class get messy.
If you are developing in eclipse, destroy the generated R class and let it rebuild itself automatically by restarting eclipse.